# Access to table user in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

How can I get the information of 2 users when I request my friends table?

My table friends is formatted like this:

```
id X , UserId : 1 , idFriend : 3, ...
```

My table User is formatted like this:

```
id X , name , mail , ...
```

When I link model user in my query, I get only the information of UserID, but I don't get the information on idFriend

My request is

```
models.Friend.findAll({
                    where: {
                        $or: [{
                            idFriend: userFound.id
                        },
                        {
                            UserID: userFound.id
                        }],
                        status: "pending"
                    },
                    include: [
                        { model: models.User },
                    ]
                })
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Define association like this in your friend model :**

```
Friend.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey : 'UserID', constraints: false});
Friend.belongsTo(User, { as: 'friend', foreignKey : 'idFriend' , constraints:false});
```

**2nd thing is include model like this :**

```
models.Friend.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [{
            idFriend: userFound.id
        },
        {
            UserID: userFound.id
        }],
        status: "pending"
    },
    include: [
        { 
            model: models.User , 
            required : false,
            where : { id : userFound.id }
        },{
            model: models.User , 
            as : 'friend', // <--------- Magic is here
            required : false,
            where : { id : userFound.id }
        }
    ]
})
```